# Convert a String to a parameter type File Flutter

Tags: string, file, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to use an image from the photo library of a users phone. It then should be displayed in this container:

```
child: Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(

        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
        ),
     child:  CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage: Image.file(path).image,
     radius: 100.0,

  )),
```

The variable **'path' is a String** and contains the path to the image. 
The error I get tells me that: *The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.*

Comment: Url path or path to your asset?

Comment: Hey, so the `Image.file` constructor has a `File` class for it.  Try this instead: `Image.file(File(path))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
              image: FileImage(File(path))
         )
    )
)
```

or fix this code from
`Image.file(path).image`
to 
`Image.file(File(path)).image`